# Javascript variables copy or reference

Tags: javascript, variables, reference

Noob here. I have an example where two variable are pointing to the same place in memory (changing the second changes the first). I can do an operation on the second variable and that will change the first. But if I try a different operation, then the values of the variables are no longer the same, meaning, I guess, that the variable are now pointing to their own places in memory.

```
  var arr1 = "john".split('');
  console.log(arr1);
  var arr2 = arr1;
  console.log(arr2 === arr1);
  arr1 = arr2.reverse(); //changes both arr1 and arr2 --meaning they are       pointing to the same object
  console.log(arr2 === arr1); //returns true
  arr1 = arr2.slice(3);//only changes arr1--meaning they are not pointing to the same object ???
  console.log(arr2 === arr1); //returns false
```

Why is this? How can you change the value of arr2 and always have it effect arr1?

Comment: Everything in JS is pass-by-value, but the value of the variable can be a reference. You probably want `var arr2 = arr1.slice()`

Comment: `arr1 = arr2.reverse(); //changes both arr1 and arr2 --meaning they are pointing to the same object` This statement is not true. Both changed because `reverse` only modifies `arr2` (in this case since arr1 and arr2 are already pointing to the same array) but then you assigned the pointer to `arr2` to `arr1`, that's why they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that some array functions modify the array "in place", but others return a brand new array without changing the original one. You just have to learn which are which.

A very quick nowhere-near-exhaustive list:

`concat()`, `slice()`, `join()`, `map()`, `filter()`, `reduce()` and `slice()` return new arrays, leaving the original unchanged.

`push()`, `pop()`, `shift()`, `unshift()` and `reverse()` modify the array they're used on.

Any decent reference site (such as developer.mozilla.org) will make it clear whether the function changes the original array or not.

In your specific example, it's worth mentioning that slice(0) would have copied the entire array, in which case arr1 and arr2 would compare equal even though arr1 is now a copy of arr2 instead of a reference to it.

Comment: Personally, one of my favorite things about compiled "systems" languages like C/C++ is that they have almost no ambiguity about when you're using copies or references. I still love Javascript as a scripting language though.

Answer (score 1):

However, if you always want the two objects to point to the same thing, wrap them somehow. For example, if the code above is written as such, it will always work.

```
var arr1 = {arr: "john".split('')};
console.log(arr1.arr);
var arr2 = arr1;
console.log(arr2.arr === arr1.arr);
arr1.arr = arr2.arr.reverse();
console.log(arr2.arr === arr1.arr); //returns true
arr1.arr = arr2.arr.slice(3);
console.log(arr2.arr === arr1.arr); //returns true
```

This is about as close as you get to a "pointer" in JavaScript and will work regardless of the type of the object.